# Can you delete or replace a python logging message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I'm looking for a way to replace or delete the last message wrote by python's logging module. The goal is to log a change in variables once it occurs. If the variable changes again, the old log message should be deleted and the new one printed instead.

Hi,

I am using pythons's logging module for a deep learning project I'm currently working on. As some GPUs just don't have enough memory to support the default batch size during training and there is no apparent connection between batch size and actual memory usage that could be used for calculations beforehand, I'm catching the runtime error once it occurs and decrease the batch size by one.
This process can be repeated quite a bit and I'm always logging which batch size did not work and which will be the next one tried. Instead of having 10-30 of these messages (or more) I'd like to simply delete the last one and replace it with the newer one instead.

I've already checked out the python logging documentation, stumbled upon the LogRecord object, but upon trying to deal with it, it seems this object does not actually keep a record of all logs, but rather saves some more info on one specific log instead.

If there is simply no way to do this, I will look into some kind of bundling solution as described here: [Python logging: bundle reoccurring messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129569/python-logging-bundle-reoccurring-messages)

The code below shows the log message I'm looking to replace.

Any help is greatly apreciated.

```py
training_not_successful = True
    while training_not_successful:
        try:
            model.run_training(global_settings['epochs'],
                               train_loader,
                               test_loader,
                               global_settings['checkpoint_output_path'],
                               model_name,
                               global_settings['best_net_criterion'])
            training_not_successful = False
        except MemoryError:
            logging.warning("Ran out of CUDA memory using batch size " + str(batch_size) +
                            ". Trying again with batch size " + str(batch_size-1))
            batch_size -= 1
            train_loader, test_loader = get_train_test_loaders(
                train_dataset_list,
                test_dataset_list,
                value_counts,
                batch_size
            )
```

Comment: Why don't you just write to a file and keep overwriting it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that the logging module does not allow to supress newlines, meaning that it's simply not possible to do something like that.

It is possible to do it with a print though:

```py
import shutil

def display(variable, rewritable=False):
    columns, lines = shutil.get_terminal_size(fallback=(80, 20))
    text = str(variable)
    filled = text + ((columns - len(text)) * ' ')
    print(filled, end='\r' if rewritable else '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from random import random
    from time import sleep

    for i in range(10):
        display(f"x = {random()}", True)
        sleep(1)
    display(f"x = 0.0") # test if old value is overwritten completely
    display("Done!")
```

Tested this on linux, but it should work everywhere. (the `shutil.get_terminal_size` function)

It's not mandatory, but very nice when entire line is overwritten as opposed to only the part that's changed.

The key is character `\r` - it returns the cursor to the end of the line, that's it. Now you can start writing from the front again, overwriting the line if it has anything else, which is exactly what you want.

Display function is simple, but I'll explain it anyway:

First line gets terminal size, what we need is the width of the line, so we can pad the text with spaces and fill entire line with spaces, to completely overwrite previous line no matter what it had.

Then we convert our variable to a string.

After that, it's just simple math, our string takes `n` characters, so the rest should be spaces, so we add `width - n` spaces to final string, and then we print it - entire line is overwritten.

`rewritable` flag allows to control when the variable should be rewritten next time you call display.

While this is not what you want, as it does not use logging module, since there's no way (that I know of) to make logging module to print `\r` instead of `\n`, I think this is a good enough substitute, that could be used if it turns out that you can indeed do this with logging module.